# Flutter Build iOS Error 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-build, flutter-ios-build

Cannot build project on iPhone 11 and above but archive and used in iPhone X. This is the error is I'm facing...

> 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Also on top of it.

> Inside AppDelegate.swift:3:8 Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

I have already tried do multiple times...

- Clean build folder
- Quit Xcode. Delete project's temp files located at
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
- Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
- Run pod install.
- Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

I'm using

> Firebase SDK 10.7.0

> XCode 14.3

> Flutter sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'

> Simulator iPhone 14 pro max

**ATTACHMENTS**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this into Podfile

```rb
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

Comment: Thank you dear, can you tell where should I add this Iine?